# Проверка доступности порта на сервере

Tags: javascript, сокет

Доброе время суток!

Интересует пара вопросов:

**1. Как при помощи javascript определить доступность порта на сервере?**

При попытке открыть страницу с несуществующим url *(http://localhost:12345)* браузер отображает сообщение о невозможности открыть страницу.

Если же открываем страницу с доступным портом, то спокойно открывает страницу. Или сбрасывает соединение, не важно. Главное - для браузера есть различие - закрыт порт (нельзя отобразить страницу) или открыт порт (отображаем, либо сбрасываем соединение).

А как это отловить через JS?
На данный момент я не могу отличить - сброшено соединение или страница недоступна.

**2. Как при отправке запроса получить header этого запроса?**

Отправлял запросы ручками через Opera.

При отправке запроса на закрытый порт показывает только URL.

Если отсылаем на открытый порт - показывает еще и тело запроса (даже если сервер сбросил соединение и страница не загрузилась).

*показывает - естественно в консоли))

Т.е. если получится перехватить эти данные, то тогда, вроде как, можно будет решить и п. 1 - потому и спрашиваю.

---

Пробовал по всякому, и WebSocket'ы пытался подключить - что-то не получилось... Может не так что-то делал?

С WebSocket'ами выдавало следующее:

- если соединение сброшено, либо порт закрыт - то сокет закрывался, разница была только в задержке между попыткой подключения к порту и его закрытием
- если страница открывалась нормально - то сокет открывался (onconnect) и почти сразу же закрывался.

Т.е. все равно не получилось различить - закрыт порт или просто соединение сбрасывается...

Судить по времени между запросом и закрытием соединения - не вариант.

Есть идеи? Вопрос по JS, поэтому FLASH и PHP не предлагать)) Таким образом и сам могу все проверить)

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, на счет есть/нет страница, открыт ли порт, то поможет AJAX, отправляете запрос на `url` и смотрите какой статус приходит

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET","http://laviro.tk");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState != 4) return;
    console.log(http.status); 
    console.log(http.getAllResponseHeaders());
}
http.send(null); // отправляем запрос
```

`http.status` - код, который нам возвращает сервер ( 404 тоже вернет )
`http.getAllResponseHeaders` - метод, возвращает все заголовки

Answer (score 0):

Вообще js это предназначен для работы на стороне клиента. Сомневаюсь что есть возможность или, что это будет правильно с точки зрения использования.

Comment: Так задача и стоит - проверить на стороне клиента доступность порта по данному адресу.

Браузер-то видит разницу - не доступен, либо доступен, но ничего не прислал. А вот предоставляет ли браузер информацию об этом - не знаю, потому и спрашиваю.